# What does Google Big Query expects in date column?

Tags: node.js, date, google-bigquery

I'm sending a JSON with some data to Google Big Query, all string and numeric columns are accepting my data just fine, however, whenever I try to send a data to the **Date** column it returns a error saying:

```
'invalid',
 location: 'creationdate',
 debugInfo: '',
 message: "Invalid date: '2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z'"
```

I'm using Node.js to work with the data and sending it to Google Big Query through the insertAll route, following the format told by them on their docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll

If I send the data as Null it works fine, I've also tried to send it as a string and as an integer, but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm is the data type on the BigQuery schema Date or Datetime?
You may need to truncate to fit the date format or switch to using datetime.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Date format in Big Query only accepts YYYY-MM-DD, without hours or timezone, I had to create another column in my table so I would be able to store the hours and timezone.